# Delphi-32 environment becomes very slow

Tags: delphi

I am running Delphi 5 on a 32-bit PC which recently had Windows 10 installed.  The Delphi environment has become extremely slow.

Running in debug mode with Task Manager visible shows that it's consuming about 35% of CPU while running an already compiled program and taking a minute or more to load the main screen where it used to take about 5 - 10 seconds at the most.

Running the executable outside the environment is as fast as it has always been.   Anyone else encountered this?

Comment: windows 10 can be run on 32bit cpu? wow, why do you need it?

Comment: Delphi 5 was released in 1999...  You're attempting to use 18 year old software on the latest version of Windows, which most definitely has changed since then.  It might be time to get a modern version of Delphi.  Borland no longer exists, and I highly doubt Embarcadero supports an ancient version of its programming language.

Comment: The software is 18 yrs old and I am 81 years old!   I only do programming now for interest and also fiddling with a stock market program I wrote years ago.   I upgraded to Windows 10 because it was available free and I assumed that Windows 7 would pass out of any support.   I have always liked Delphi and regretted that after version 5 the cost started go out of my reach.

Comment: @Zulukas: It should normally be possible to run Delphi 5 programs on Windows 10 without any big slowdowns. But some changes in Windows 10 might be a hindrance, like new restrictions on certain API calls, different access rights for various aspects of the OS, etc.

Comment: @ron: Delphi Starter Edition is free or pretty cheap, these days.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we can't possibly troubleshoot *this 18 year old IDE runs slow on Windows 10* issues. A large part of the reason it runs slowly is that Windows 10 requires large amounts of RAM, and running a 32-bit version by definition limits it to 4GB of RAM max. 4GB barely meets the minimum system requirements of Windows 10.

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis thanks for the response.   I have downloaded the Starter edition as you suggest and will see how that goes

Comment: Starter edition will suffer the same. Embarcadero is still working on hotfix for their latest version.

Comment: @Ken White: "4GB barely meets the minimum system requirements of Windows 10". As evident from [Windows 10 Specifications & Systems Requirements](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/windows-10-specifications) this is simply wrong.

Comment: @mghie: You seriously think 1GB is the actual realistic minimum requirement? Have you *tried* running even Windows 2000 on that RAM?

Comment: @Ken White: Yes, I have written software for machine control which run quite happily on Windows 2000 even with 256 or 512 MB RAM, for months on end. That this was possible with Delphi was always one of its highlights. What's your point? If you think dozen CPU cores and several GB of RAM are necessary today then surely the recent (I don't think modern would be an apt word) Delphi versions are to blame, not Windows.

Comment: @dalija   Thanks for your posting, I have read Marco Cantu's report also.  My old Delphi5 IDE and apps ran well before the Creators upgrade so I think the rather dismissive reply and vote to close the question was hasty.

Comment: @ron to be honest, this kind of questions is usually hard to answer and usually answers consist of a lot of wild guessing. And that is one of the reasons why generally people will vote to close them. It is just pure luck that yours is rather recognizable already known issue.

Comment: "the cost started go out of my reach" - there is Lazarus. Also, in Europe you are allowed to buy (sell) a second hand license.

Comment: @KenWhite "I'm voting to close this question as off-topic"  - I am glad the others did not voted also and that the question is still open. As you can see , you are simply wrong. The problem is not the 18 years old IDE but the new Windows 10!

Answer (score 9):

This is known issue affecting all Delphi versions running on Windows 10 Creators update.

Non-functional debugger after updating to Windows 10 Creators
https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-17972

> The debugger goes haywire for everyone in our organization with
>   Creators and Tokyo/Berlin. Reverting to Windows Anniversary brings
>   back the sanity.
>
> Debugger problems with Tokyo/Berlin and Creators:
>
> App takes a long time to load with modules loading and unloading and
>   re-loading many times
>
> IDE freezes
>
> Memory consumption of bds.exe explodes, sometimes (> 3GB)
>
> I will attached before and after screenshots showing how modules load
>   and unload and re-load with Windows 10 Creators.
>
> I presume these problems have the same root cause(s) than those in
>   https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=884382

Issue is caused by newly introduced optimizations in Windows dll (bpl) loading. It does not affect standalone exe applications.

Embarcadero is working with Microsoft in fixing this in future Windows update and/or hotfix.

More info: http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/2017-june-delphi-packages-creators-update.html

Comment: If I got this correctly, the issue was fixed by Microsoft in the Windows 10 Fall Creator's Update.

Comment: @dummzeuch Fall Creator's Update should have corrected the issue. However, my machine fails to install Fall Creator's Update so I cannot confirm that the issue is really solved.

Comment: It is still mega slow, using Windows 10 1909 and C++ Builder 2007 !

Comment: @Lumo AFAIK that Windows fix did not completely reverted behavior, so some slowdown still occurs. I am not sure if Embarcadero added some additional fixes on their side, but if they had only newer Delphi versions would have them.

Comment: Sadly there is no fix for this issue for older applications other than perhaps running the dev. environment in a VM. My Delphi 7 application takes about 30 seconds to run inside the IDE while less than 1 seconds without debugging.